# Check if a property exists in a jsonb column

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm facing a problem filtering rows by property in a `jsonb` column type.

I tried this:

```
jsonb_column ? 'my_property'
```

On `pgadmin` or `psql` it works well, but over a JDBC driver it throws the error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter count: 3, actual parameters: []
```

The problem is with the `?` operator. So, there're another way to do that?

Comment: make sure you have appropriate version of the driver; it would be good if try to include code snippet you are using

Comment: I changed my driver to the latest (9.4.1208), but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, after some researches and no one solution to my problem with the "?" operator over de JDBC driver, I solved it another way, the function

> jsonb_object_keys

returns all keys of my json element, and then I filter each one using the [<@](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) operator like:

```
ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_object_keys(jsonb_column)) <@ '{property1,property2,property3}'
```